# JS method calling with return

Tags: javascript

```
var DOM_N$ = function(selector){
    this.selector = selector;
    return "jello world";
}
DOM_N$.prototype = {
    getSelector: function(){
        return this.selector;
    }
}
function N$(selector){
    return (new DOM_N$(selector));
}

N$('element').selector; //wont return selector because of return
N$('element'); //returns element
```

I am trying to return the values from an object when no other methods are being called but my return is interrupting my objects methods.

Comment: No, you cannot return both.

Comment: But i want to, & Jquery does it.

Comment: in jquery $('element'); will return and has methods to call with it

Comment: No, jQuery doesn't do it. jQuery does always return a collection of elements. I really don't get what you want this `return this.nodes;` to do. Just omit it.

Comment: this.nodes (not changed that line to jello world) is suppose to return a value of compatible elements.

Comment: i think it will help if you'll provide us with an "expected result vs actual result"

Comment: Ohhhhhhh @ bergi thanks now i get how Jquery does it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For DOM_N$ be a constructor, it should returns nothing

```
var DOM_N$ = function(selector){
    this.selector = selector;
}
```